# extreme point of a convex set

Tags: banach-spaces, proof-explanation

In [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880406), lemma $2.3.1$ states that

> Suppose $E$ is a normed real linear space . Then $z^*$ is an extreme point of $B(E^*)$ if and only if $E(z^*)-E(z^*)=E$ where $E(z^*)=\{ x \in E: \|x\|-z^*(x) \leq 1\}$ and $B(E^*)=\{f \in E:\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1\}$

The following is the proof:

Let $z^* \in B(E^*)$. The convex set $E(z^*)-E(z^*)$ has a nonempty interior and so if it is not all of $E$, then there exists $y^*$ in $E^*$ such that $y^*(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in E(z^*)-E(z^*)$ and in fact $|y^*(x)| \leq 1$ for all such $x$. Let  $x \in B(E)$ and suppose $\alpha=\|x\|-z^*(x)$. First assume that $\alpha=0$. Then $\lambda x \in E(z^*)$ for every $\lambda > 0$ and since $|y^*(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda$. we must have $y^*(x)=0$. It follows that $(z^* \pm y^*)(x)=z^*(x) \leq 1$. If $\alpha >0$, then $\alpha^{-1}x \in E(z^*)$ so that $|y^*(\alpha^{-1}x)| \leq 1$. Hence, $\pm y^*(x) \leq \alpha =\|x\| - z^*(x)$ and $(z^* \pm y^*)(x) \leq 1$. We conclude that $z^* \pm y^* \in B(E^*)$ and so $z^*$ cannot be an extreme point.

Questions:

1. Why the set $E(z^*)-E(z^*)$ has a nonempty interior?
2. If it is not all of $E$, then there exists $y^*$ in $E^*$ such that $y^*(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in E(z^*)-E(z^*)$ and in fact $|y^*(x)| \leq 1$ for all such $x$. Why?

For question $2$, it seems that it is related to Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem but I don't know what is the relation.

Comment: @user117818: there is no typo, it is $E(z^*)-E(z^*)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, one can show that $0$ is in the interior of $E(z^*)-E(z^*)$.
In fact, $0$ is already in the interior of $E(z^*)$. Indeed, since $z^* \in E^*$
this is a continuous map, so there is a constant $C$ such that 
$|z^*(x)| \leq C||x||$ for every $x\in E$. Then if we put
$\varepsilon={\sf min}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2C})$, for any
$x\in B(0,\varepsilon)$ we have $||x||\leq \frac{1}{2}$
and $|z^*(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ so $x\in E(z^*)$.

For Q2, this is indeed a corollary of Hahn-Banach as you guessed.
Indeed, use the geometric Hahn-Banach theorem (see
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) on Wikipedia) 
with $K=E(z^*)-E(z^*)$ where
$V=\lbrace v \rbrace$ where $v$ is any point not in $K$.